# Can python plotnine draw charts on web application?

Tags: python, data-visualization, fastapi, plotnine

I'm learning fastapi web framework for my data science visualization project.

I know python plotnine is usually used on notebook or something. Can I use plotnine to draw any ggplot2 charts on the web framework?

Any data visualization library to work with fastapi and python is welcome, except plotly dash.

Or, if there are other web framework and visualization library combinations recommendable for small and medium size biz, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, you can use Plotnine to render an SVG or PNG or whatnot you serve to the web.

Comment: Thanks, with plotinine's draw() and FastAPI's StreamingResponse(), I got matplotlib Figure as PNG file at the endpoint